# Why does my gutenberg block get a 'This block contains unexpected or invalid content error' when changing Font size using RangeControl

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

So I've been trying to set a font size based on user input on my gutenberg block. Here is how the edit section is setup:

```
titleSize: {
    type: 'string',
    default: null
}

function handleTitleSize(value) {
    props.setAttributes({
        titleSize: value
    })
}

<PanelBody title={'Title Settings'}>
    <p><strong>Select a Title Color:</strong></p>

    <ColorPalette 
        value={titleColor}
        onChange={handleTitleColorChange}
    />

    <RangeControl 
        label="Font Size"
        value={titleSize}
        onChange={handleTitleSize}
        min={12}
        max={60}
    />

    <p><strong>Select Title Alignment:</strong></p>

    <AlignmentToolbar 
        value={titleAlignment}
        onChange={handleTitleAlignment}
    />
</PanelBody>
```

This is in the save method:

```
<div class="hero-block-subtitle" style={
    { 
        color: titleColor,
        textAlign: titleAlignment,
        fontSize: titleSize
    }
}>{title}</div>
```

Everything else seems to work fine but when the font size is changed using the RangeControl, the block gives me the error on reload. Am I setting this up wrong or missing something? This is the only place where I see this kind of behavior, the alignment and the color changes seem to work fine.

I have also tried the FontSizePicker and see the same behavior.

Would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so the problem was me defining the font size as a string, instead of a number.

```
titleSize: {
    type: 'string',
    default: null
}
```

should be:

```
titleSize: {
    type: 'number',
    default: 16
}
```